# Pass the "-h" argument to the sub-script

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I have a main script that takes options that lead to several other scripts:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-option1', action = "store_true")
group.add_argument('-option2', action = "store_true")

args = parser.parse_known_args()
print args
print args[0].option1
print args[0].option2

if args[0].option1:
    print "running sub_script.py"
    import sub_script
    sub_script.main(args[1])
```

Then the sub-script:

```
def main(namespace):
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument('-sub')

    args = parser.parse_args(namespace)

    print args
    print args.sub

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, I cannot pass the `-h` to `sub_script.py`, instead it returns the help document of the main script. It there a way by tell `argparse` to display the help document of the other script instead, for example by using:

```
python main_script.py -option1 -sub -h
```

Comment: I think you want a [sub-command](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands), which has its own help.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a parser gets a `-h` help action.  That action displays the help message and exits.  So in your case, the first parser catches the `-h` and acts, without moving on to the second parser.

You can turn that off with:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
```

Now `-h` means nothing to the first parser, and it can call the second one.  You could get a help from both parsers if you define a different `help` argument for the parser that gets this `add_help=False`.

If you use the subcommand/subparser mechanism described in the documentation, (`jonrsharpe's` comment)

```
 python prog.py -h
```

will give the help for the main, showing the `option1/option2` choices, and

```
 python prog.py option1 -h
```

will show help for the `option1` subparser.  Getting help from both parsers is trickier and been the subject of several SO questions.